# jQuery: Get previous element minus 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select the pre-previous element of an item with a class.

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>Element I want</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li class="selector">5</li>
</ul>
```

As far as I understand it, the `.prev()` selector only gets the immediately preceding sibling.

So I tried the following:

```
$("li>li").prev().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

But that doesn't work. 
There is always a different amount of items in that list. So I have to go backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's several ways to do this. You could either use `prev().prev()`:

```
$(".selector").prev().prev().css("background-color", "red");
```

Or `prevAll().slice()`

```
$('.selector').prevAll().slice(1, 2).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Of if the target is always the third from the start in the container, you can select it directly using `:eq()`:

```
$('ul li:eq(3)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or if the target is always third from the end you can select it directly using `:nth-last-child()`:

```
$('ul li:nth-last-child(3)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Whichever method you choose, don't use `css()` as it's not a good separation of concerns (because it ties the CSS and JS logic together). Use `addClass()` instead.

```js
//$(".selector").prev().prev().addClass('red');
//$('ul li:eq(3)').addClass('red');
//$('.selector').prevAll().slice(1, 2).addClass('red');
$('ul li:nth-last-child(3)').addClass('red');
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>Element I want</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li class="selector">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, that's it! And I'm using `addClass()`, `css()` was just for demonstration.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: @Cray you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I have to wait 2 more minutes :-)